# Java change "value" element on a map.entry list

Tags: java

I have this hashmap which is a key-value of name of person, and their money:

`dict = {Charlie=60.0, Ema=60.0, David=-20.0, Fred=-60.0, Gabe=-40.0}`

I needed to sort this by its values, so I made it into a list using this:

```
this.list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Double>>(this.dict.entrySet());
list.sort(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> o1, Map.Entry<String, Double> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
});
```

and it works perfectly, so now i have a list:
`this.list = [Fred=-60.0, Gabe=-40.0, David=-20.0, Charlie=60.0, Ema=60.0]`

What I need to do is to change the value of the first element-value, so the first element would be Fred=-30.0 for example.
and also I need to delete the last element completely.

Is this possible?
I come from python, and trying to translate some code to Java :D

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc for `LinkedList` would be beneficial for you to read...

> change the value of the first element-value

```
list.element().setValue(-30.0)
```

> delete the last element completely

```
list.removeLast()
```

Comment: for some reason i cant get it to work with .removeLast()
i managed to make it work with `this.list.remove(this.list.get(this.list.size()-1));`

Also the set value one I managed like this `this.list.get(0).setValue(-30);` 
is it correct to use like this tho?

Comment: @Gunnar how is `list` defined? If it's a `List`, well, `removeLast` is a method of `LinkedList`, not `List`. Java is statically typed, so it won't allow a call to a method that isn't on the declared type without a cast.

Comment: Oooh i just noticed that I did actually define as `List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> list;`
Thanks for the help, anyway you helped me figured out even if i defined wrong haha

Comment: @Gunnar Using `.get(int index)` is valid, too